# How to use a search bar on site to search sub urls

Tags: javascript, html, css, searchbar

I need to find out how to have a search bar that can find other pages on my site. Doing a google search, I can only find the code to create a search bar, and not utilise it. Its features would need to include auto correct and actually going to the page, basically these 2 things combined (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In the [how to filter/search list](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp) example you can just add the urls to the corresponding links like `<li><a href="www.example.com/adele">Adele</a></li>`.

And in the [how to js autocomplete](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp) example it will be a bit different and additional code needs to be written. If the url is the same as the items in the list there would not be an issue, but otherwise you need to make the array of countries into an array of objects so that each object will have the name of the country and the corresponding url. Then in the javascript function you will have to access the components as `arr[x].country`.

The array of countries should look something like this

```
`var countries = [{country:"Afghanistan", url:"afghanistan"}, {country:"Albania", url:"albania"},...}.
```

Then add an onClick event handler in the javascript function.

```
onClick="location.href=`www.example.com/${arr[x].url}`"
```